# how to make it mirror effect

Tags: jquery, html

```
<li id="li_id1" class="li_img1">
    <div>
        <a href="#"><img id="imge1" class="img1" src="img/slide_001.png" alt="My Profile" />
            <canvas id="canvas1"></canvas>  
        </a>
     </div>
</li>

var img_path="img/slide_01.png";
var context = document.getElementById(canvas1).getContext("2d");
var img = new Image();
img.src = img_path;
context.translate(0, 0); 
context.scale(-1,1) 
context.rotate(-3.09);

img.onload = function() {
    context.drawImage(img,0, -205,190,190);
}
```

I think I have to put the gradation in order to make it mirror effect.
Any thought for that
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion is to use one of the plugins to apply a mirror effect.  Here is one:

http://www.digitalia.be/software/reflectionjs-for-jquery

Here is a duplicate question to answer your specific question:  [Create reflected image with HTML Canvas?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1693339/create-reflected-image-with-html-canvas)